# How to make Angular 2 pick up dynamically added routerLink directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

As seen in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K906Y8KtkgYVgAIsCLqE?p=preview), I'm dynamically adding an HTML to one of my elements, which boils down to this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: `<span [innerHTML]="link"></span>`,
}) export class MyComponent {
    private linkContent = '<a routerLink="/my-route">GoTo Route</a>';
    private link;

    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.link = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(linkContent);
    }
}
```

This results in `<a routerLink="/my-route">GoTo Route</a>` being added to the DOM, but Angular knows nothing about the `routerLink` directive on this element, and does not "bind" to it. So, when you click the link, it results in complete reload with re-bootstrap (which doesn't work in plunk, it just gives a 404).

**Question**: how to tell angular to go through the DOM (or its part, or even a single element) and perform component initialization if needed?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you want to do here but, by your Plunker, I guess your issue is that the `login` link isn't working, right? If so, why are you using the `routerLink` inside your localization instead of using it in your template?

Comment: Hey.. How did you solve the issue to dynamically add routerlink to anchor tag from type script class.? I tried hard to create dynamic component but no success. Please help me out.

Comment: @MeenakshiKumari I didn't go down that path eventually, but restructured my code to not have dynamic links instead

Comment: Actually I did the same.. Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular2 doesn't process HTML added dynamically in any way except sanitization.

Passing `'<a routerLink="/my-route">GoTo Route</a>'` to `innerHTML` is doing exactly this, passing this string to the DOM, but nothing else. There is no `routerLink` directive being instantiated or applied.

If you need to add HTML dynamically that uses Angular2 bindings, directives, or components, you can add the HTML to a components template, and add this component dynamically using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` like demonstrated for example in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)